# Select date in oracle db

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date

I set or insert time in a postgres table value with now()::timestamp

But it does not work in oracle db.

This is the table:

```
create table types
(
    id          number                                                                                               not null,
    description varchar(255)                                                                                         not null,
    created_at  timestamp                                                                                            null,
    updated_at  timestamp                                                                                            null,
    deleted_at  timestamp                                                                                            null,
    CONSTRAINT autenticacion_id   PRIMARY KEY (id)

);
```

So to insert the data I make:

```
insert into types (id, description) values (1, 'hello world', now()::timestamp)
```

But I get:

> ORA-00917: missing comma

```
insert into types (id, description) values (1, 'hello world', (select sysdate from dual))
```

I get:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Just `SYSDATE`.  Also see https://database-heartbeat.com/2021/09/28/sysdate-vs-current_date-in-oracle-database/

Comment: Functions and operators differ from one DBMS to another. There is no `NOW` function inOracle, and there is no casting with `::`. To get thje current timestamp use `SYSTIMESTAMP` in Oracle. And it is common in Oracle not to use `VARCHAR`, but `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: And you are missing a column name: `insert into types (id, description)` = two columns, `values (1, 'hello world', systimestamp)`= three columns.

Comment: Your second statement should work, although you don't need a subquery at all. Are you sure the types table exists? Your `CREATE TABLE` statement lacks commas.

Comment: Why are you using Oracle? I saw most of your questions and you seems to now know much about programming, so why are you in need of using an Oracle database and just having weird issues no one else have because they use MySQL or Postgress? Legit question, not questioning your thinking or needs. Just want to make sure you are pointed into a successful path instead of a failure path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are providing 3 values and have only given 2 columns that you want to insert into.
- `SYSDATE` is a `DATE` data type and `SYSTIMESTAMP` is a `TIMESTAMP` data type; they both have a date and time component but `SYSTIMESTAMP` also has fractional seconds (and a time zone, but that will be ignored as the column you are inserting into is a `TIMESTAMP` and not a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type).

What you probably want is:

```sql
INSERT INTO types (id, description, created_at)
VALUES (1, 'hello world', SYSTIMESTAMP)
```

However, you may want to consider that the timestamp should be in a specific time zone (typically UTC):

```sql
INSERT INTO types (id, description, created_at)
VALUES (1, 'hello world', SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

*Note: You can wrap a value in `(SELECT value FROM DUAL)` but it is not necessary.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VXHjSQr2)